# In Python, when iterating through items in list, how to start at 0 if end is reached?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I am iterating through a list in Python.

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
i = 0
while i <= 27:
    print mylist[i]
    i +=1
```

I am looking for a simple / elegant solutition so that when i is 11, it grabs 'a' from mylist.  I'd rather not use a complex set of if statments to check if the end of the list is reached.  Also, I would rather not make a new list with mylist duplicated numerous times, as these lists are rather long.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try modulo math:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
i = 0
while i <= 27:
    print mylist[i % len(mylist)]
    i +=1
```

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

Comment: Thank you, but isn't this just the same, resource-wise, as duplicating mylist and appending it to itself until its length is equal to 27 in this case?

Comment: This option isn't going to support indexed access. (Though of course, the code would benefit from being rewritten to use iteration.)

Comment: @zacharydimaria It's not quite the same as duplicating mylist and appending it until the length is 27. The `itertools.cycle(...)` method will save a copy of each element of the iterable on the first cycle, then return these copies indefinitely. So it would make at most one copy of the original iterable.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of Falmarri's answer, I can't resist adding this:

```
def modrange(first, last, modulus, step = 1):
    for i in xrange(first, last, step):
        yield i % modulus
```

Now you can rewrite your while loop as:

```
for i in modrange(0, 27, len(mylist)):
    print mylist[i]
```